# double values not displaying with cout

Tags: c++, user-input

In the program, I have to create a function to fill elements in an array of type double, and then display them using another function show(). Now, when I input a simple numbers, like: 1,2,3,4,5; the show function doesn't display those numbers, but instead, garbage values like: 8.586689e+273.

I can't figure out what is wrong, especially when I have another program open right here, which is printing the numbers out just fine.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

int fill(double arr[], int);
void show(const double arr[], int);
void reverse(double arr[], int);
const int size = 5;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double arr[size];

int limit = fill(arr,size);

show(arr,limit);
reverse(arr,limit);
show(arr,limit);

return 0;
}

int fill(double arr[], int size)
{
cout<<"Enter the values to fill the array: "<<endl;
int i,temp;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<"Enter entry #"<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>temp;
        if(!cin){
                    cin.clear();
                    while(cin.get()!='\n')
                        continue;
                    cout<<"Bad Input.Input Process Terminated.";
                    break;
                }
        else if(temp<0){
            break;
            arr[i]=temp;
        }
    }
return i;
}


void show(const double ar[], int n)
{
using namespace std;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Entry #"<<(i+1)<<": ";
        cout<<ar[i]<<endl;
    }
}

void reverse(double arr[], int limit)
{
    cout<<"Reversing values..."<<endl;
    double temp;
    for(int i=0;i<limit/2;i++){
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[limit-i-1];
        arr[limit-i-1]=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to say...looks like copied homework with 1 misplaced } bracket.

Comment: Not homework...I'm teaching myself from a book called C++ Primer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not filling the area. Note where you were trying to do so. You put it inside the temp<0 condition, after the break statement. Therefore it is never executed. 
Since your array is uninitialized (you should use a vector instead), it contains weird values which aren't displayed properly.

```
int fill(double arr[], int size)
{
cout<<"Enter the values to fill the array: "<<endl;
int i,temp;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<"Enter entry #"<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>temp;
        if(!cin){
                    cin.clear();
                    while(cin.get()!='\n')
                        continue;
                    cout<<"Bad Input.Input Process Terminated.";
                    break;
                }
        else if(temp<0){
            break;
        }
        arr[i]=temp;
    }
return i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...seems most of the problems I face are because of my own stupid little mistakes. This is something I need to work on.

Answer (score 1):

You not storing the data into your array.  So the array contains garbage, and displays garbage.

I'm guessing this code:

```
    else if(temp<0){
        break;
        arr[i]=temp;
    }
```

...should instead have been:

```
    else if(temp<0){
        break;
    }
    arr[i]=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of careless mistake.

```
else if(temp<0){
            break;
           //^^^^^ After break
            arr[i]=temp;
           //How can you expect the next line to get executed.
        }
```